# back button doesn't go back

Tags: ios, objective-c

After pushing a ViewController using this code

```
UIViewController *vc = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"frontCardViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

I remove all ViewControllers I don't need anymore using this code

```
NSMutableArray *navigationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:navigationArray];
for (UIViewController *viewController in array) {
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[RITCardViewController class]]) {
            RSLog(@"Is kind of Class RITCardViewController");
            [navigationArray removeObject:viewController];
    }
}
self.navigationController.viewControllers = navigationArray;
```

The navigation array now looks like this:

```
"RITMainViewController: 0x10d81fc1>",
"RITDetailViewController: 0x10d847880",
"RITTestResultViewController: 0x113d0e090"
```

But the problem is that if the back button in the navigation bar is pressed now, it goes back to the second screen. But when the back button is pressed again it just stays on this screen. It seems to go trough all the screens I have removed, but doesn't show them.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The whole point of a navigation controller is to push new controllers on to a stack, and allow the user to then go back down the stack by hitting the back button. You should never be manually removing ones that aren't visible any more.

Removing controllers from the navigation stack like that is never going to work; you're corrupting its internal state and it's bound to get hopelessly confused. It's also going to produce a terrible user experience; people expect navigation to work in a way they're accustomed to it working.

Comment: @davidf2281 you are wrong in thinking that it corrupts the internal state. I have done this in the past quite successfully. You are very right however in highlighting the user experience of the application.

Comment: I do agree with @bensarz suggestion. However, depending on the acutal navigation logic, using `popToViewController:animated:`could be an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this instead:

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [@[] mutableCopy];
for (UIViewController *vc in self.nagivationController.viewControllers)
{
    if (NO == [vc isKindOfClass:[RITCardViewController class]])
        [viewControllers addObject:vc];
}
self.navigationController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
```

Make sure you don't corrupt the stack by removing the view controller you are currently on from the view controllers array. Assuming your current view controller is not an instance of `RITCardViewController` you should be fine. Otherwise, you'll have to make up for it in your code.